# Unable to run `gh auth login --with-token < token` in a Docker container

Tags: docker, github-cli

Running `gh auth login --with-token < token` inside an Ubuntu 22.04 Docker image fails with:

```
error validating token: Get "https://api.github.com/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I can reproduce this error by running:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:latest
apt-get update && apt-get -y install gh
echo '<my token>' > token
gh auth login --with-token < token
```

Note: I have already learned that this is not the recommended way to script `gh` command line usage, but I am still troubled that I do not understand this.  The recommended authentication for scripting is setting `GH_TOKEN`, which should get me through my current task.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have figured this out: the `gh` apt package does not depend on the `git` apt package.

After I `apt-get -y install git`, I am now able to `gh auth login --with-token < token` as evidenced by checking status:

```
gh auth status
github.com
  ✓ Logged in to github.com as <username> (/root/.config/gh/hosts.yml)
  ✓ Git operations for github.com configured to use https protocol.
  ✓ Token: *******************
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set the github token as an env variable `$GITHUB_TOKEN` in the docker file, then no need to run the `gh auth login`.